# Inserting a OneDrive presentation into Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, powerpoint, onedrive

I have a PowerPoint presentation that is uploaded to OneDrive. To embed the presentation, OneDrive tells me to use the following code and paste it into the Text area of my Wordpress page:

```
<iframe src='https://shaarei-my.sharepoint.com/personal/office_shaarei_org/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc={3b46efde-157e-4112-842a-eebc316e36cd}&action=embedview&wdAr=1.7777777777777777' width='350px' height='221px' frameborder='0'>
  This is an embedded 
  <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com'>Microsoft Office</a> presentation, powered by <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com/webapps'>Office Online</a>.
</iframe>
```

When I insert this into my Text area, it just becomes an anchored link. No shortcode appears. I am following the instructions, I think, quite closely. However, all that appears when I view the page is the link.

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: you followed this right ? https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Embed-a-PowerPoint-presentation-on-a-web-page-b2073264-7707-46d2-84d1-b68a42825bcf

Comment: also, did you switch to html mode n your editor when inserting the html code ?